# How can I hide endpoints from Swagger UI in Servicestack?

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I'm using the Swagger plugin for ServiceStack 3.9.59.0. I have a few endpoints, for example /selfchecknode, in my ServiceStack API that I don't want to show up in the Swagger UI.

Is there a declarative way, perhaps via a contract attribute, that I can use to hide specific endpoints from showing up in Swagger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Security docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Security) show how you can restrict visibility and access to ServiceStack. So you can hide it from being visible externally with:

```
[Restrict(VisibleInternalOnly = true)]
public class InternalAdmin { }
```

Comment: That's awesome that works for Swagger too! I believe my NGinx proxy, which runs on the same box as IIS, is making the request look local to ServiceStack.