# Security Restrict Services in ServiceStack and Fluent API

Tags: servicestack

Reading the answer in  [How can I hide endpoints from Swagger UI in Servicestack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143059/how-can-i-hide-endpoints-from-swagger-ui-in-servicestack)

and the  [Security Restrict Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Security#restrict-services)  documentation.

is it possible    to register   restrictions , using a  Fluent API, as we do with Routes ?

adding in a table in  AppHost Configure ?

there are a lot of advantages, configuring the services, in one place, by this way.

Also, can we restrict services using custom EndpointAttributes or (another way) ?

e.g depending on user ?